# Missing functions from chron package

Tags: r, chron

The CRAN documentation for the [chron package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/chron/chron.pdf) has the function trunc.times(). However, even after updating and reloading the chron package in R, no such function is found. Has this function been removed and the documentation just hasn't been updated yet? Are there more than one chron packages? Really need to find away to get that functionality.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function is still there, but not exported.  You need to use `chron:::trunc.times`   (three colons).

If you really don't like those triple colons,  you can get the function yourself using
`trunc.times = getFromNamespace("trunc.times", "chron")`

I don't know a good way to get a listing of internal functions that are *not* exported, but you can get a listing of what was imported when you loaded the package using
`ls("package:chron")`

Comment: Thanks that did it. Is there a way to export it so I don't have to always use the ::: colons? Also, for future reference, is there a way to tell if a function has or hasn't been exported?

Comment: @C.Denney Only the package developer has control over what functions are exported (unless you download the source code, modify it, and build an altered version of the package yourself). The quickest way to tell is often to just type the function at the console and if it isn't found, it isn't exported.

Answer (score 2):

`trunc.times` is a method associated with the `trunc` generic.  You are supposed to call the generic, not the method directly.  That is why the package does not export it.

Here is an example of how to use it.

```
library(chron)
trunc(times("01:01:01"), "hour")
## [1] 01:00:00
```

The Examples section of `?trunc.times` has more examples.